# Nested each and if with Handlebars and EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have two list of models which have relations.

```
A has many B
```

I loop through `B` with `{{#each}}` and generate a `<table>` with it and every row has a `<select>` where all `A`s, that exist, are listed.

If an `B` belongs to an `A` it should be selected in the `<select>`

Example:

```
<table>
  {{#each b in listofb}}
    <tr><td>
      <select>
        {{#each a in listofa}}
          {{#if b belongsto a}}
            <option selected>a.someAttribute</option>
          {{else}}
            <option>a.someAttribute</option>
          {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
      </select>
    </td></tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

There is probably a way to do this with handlebar-helpers, but I don't know if I can use their output later with Ember controller actions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ember.Select` http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html

```
{{view 'select' value=someControllerProperty}}
```

It helps you keep logic inside the controller.

Now, in the controller you can react upon changes to the value selected with:

```
processValueChange: function() {
  // do stuff
}.property('someControllerProperty')
```

Comment: I got this thing bound to my property, but I don't get a default selected value set. `{{view 'select' class="form-control" content=accounts optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.username"}}`tried selection=key.owner (where an account model is stored) but this didn't work

Comment: Also `{{log key.owner.id}}` shows me the right ID, so the related model should be resolved.

Comment: Your are not setting the default value, use the `value` property just as I typed it. For further helpe setup an http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Comment: I generate these selects in an each loop and end up with a bunch of them, so I cannot bind directly to one controller property. I tried to bind it to a model property that changes also in the each loop, but `value` and `valueBinding` didn't work.